# why active directory computer object has machine password?

Tags: windows, active-directory, domain-controller, entra-id

The active directory computer object (ie machine object) also have password , as far as i know only the user's logon name and users password is used when logging into the domain joined computer ? But still why machine password is there and what is the use for it.
Reference Links : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/machine-account-password-process/ba-p/396026
Clear Explanation appreciated thank you!
EDIT :
I tried googling it read few articles about it and yet those articles doesn't explained why we have it and explain more about password age and other stuffs . If some one explain me why and where is passwords is used will be really useful

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it shows no sign of attempted research.

Comment: This is a question that can be answered by typing [`purpose of machine account password active directory`](https://www.google.com/search?q=purpose+of+machine+account+password+active+directory) into a Google search. We expect that people *attempt* to find answers before asking ServerFault.

Comment: Dude just calm i tried and researched a lot https://syfuhs.net/on-computer-passwords and https://4sysops.com/archives/active-directory-passwords-all-you-need-to-know/ i cant find exact thing it used it say secure channel or acting for you and i cant get a clear picture . I came here to get a deep view on this topic not a higher level explanation.

Comment: PS : I know about googling stuff i came to server fault to get a deeper knowledge and by googling i didnt understand it. Thank you btw

Comment: First of all, I found very good descriptions of the purpose using google. Second, have a look at the [tour page](https://serverfault.com/tour), which explicitly asks you not to ask about learning materials.

Answer (score 1):

The computer account is a type of user account. It needs to logon and access resources, independent of any user account. To do this, it needs to specify credentials, in the form of a username and password. For example, when applying Group Policy, the computer needs to access and read files on the SYSVOL share on the domain controller.

Comment: Thanks it makes sense now *** When your computer wants to act as itself on the network (instead of, say, you) it uses it's password to authenticate to the domain controller. Things running as SYSTEM or NETWORK SERVICE operate as the computer account on the network.*** I found this in a article can you explain me what this means?